# c++11 difftime() calculating leap year incorrectly?

Tags: c++, c++11, difftime

I make a simple program to calculate the number of day between two days:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    struct tm t1 = {0,0,0,28,2,104};
    struct tm t2 = {0,0,0,1,3,104};
    time_t x = mktime(&t1);
    time_t y = mktime(&t2);
    cout << difftime(y,x)/3600/24 << endl;

}
```

The output is 4 however, my expected result is 1. May I know where is the problem is ?

Comment: Months start at `0` not `1`, thus `2` is march and `3` is april, and there always 4 days between march the 28th and april 1st.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `struct tm`, months are counted from `0` to `11` (not `1` to `12`), thus `2` is March and `3` is April, you code output the number of days between March the 28<sup>th</sup> and April 1<sup>st</sup>, which is 4.

The correct version would be:

```
struct tm t1 = {0, 0, 0, 28, 1, 104};
struct tm t2 = {0, 0, 0,  1, 2, 104};
```

By the way, 2004 is a leap year and thus February had 29 days, there were **two days** between February the 28<sup>th</sup> and March the 1<sup>st</sup> (not one).

`difftime` gives you the number of seconds between `02/28/2004 00:00:00` and `03/01/2004 00:00:00` (the first day is accounted for in the difference).

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the clear explanation !

Comment: Cool, so month 0 is not just a Java issue! Perhaps Java has been ported from C++.